# Why am I receiving undefined values in both input's of my form (User selected Image file + Image title (not filename) ) when making request to my API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to allow a user to input an image file with a title input (text) for that image. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my front end? My API is working on postman but for some reason it isn't pulling the user inputted value for both the image that is selected (,jpeg,.svg, .png) + the title inputted for the image on the frontend side.
I am receiving undefined for some reason when trying to push to my API through React and am not sure what is going on.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

Upload.jsx:

```html
import '../../components/pages/styles/Uploads.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import authHeader from '../../services/auth-header';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/user/posts';

function Uploads() {
    const {user: currentUser} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        watch,
        formState: {errors},
    } = useForm();
    console.log(watch('title'));

    const [file, setFile] = useState();
    const [title, setTitle] = useState();
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {}, []);

    const onAddImage = (file) => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
        if (!file) return;
        setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    };
    const onSubmit = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('title', title);

        const result = await axios.post(API_URL + '/upload', formData, {
            headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        });
        console.log(result.data);
    };

    return (
        <div className='page'>
            <div className='upload-card'>
                <div id='preview'>
                    <img
                        src={preview || require('../../assets/user-solid.jpeg')}
                        id='image'
                        alt='Thumbnail'
                        className='user-post'
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='upload-container'>
                <div className='post-form-container'>
                    <p id='upload-form-label'>Hello, feel free to post an image!</p>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='upload-form'>
                        <div className='panel'>
                            <div className='button_outer'>
                                <div className='btn_upload'>
                                    <input
                                        filename={file}
                                        onChange={(e) => onAddImage(e.target.files[0])}
                                        type='file'
                                        accept='.jpeg,.svg,.gif,.png'
                                        id='image-selection-btn'
                                        name='file'
                                    ></input>
                                    Choose your Art
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input
                            {...register('title', {required: true})}
                            type='text'
                            name='title'
                        />

                        <button type='submit' id='post-upload-btn'>
                            Upload Image
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Uploads;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `onSubmit` you try to add `file` and `title` to your `formData` but you never use `setFile` and `setTitle` so they stay as the initial value that you did not assign

```
const blob = new Blob([title], {type : 'text/plain'})
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('title', blob);
```

Inside `onAddImage` you can use `setFile(file)` and I do not know data type if there is name or title inside your file object `setTitle(file?.name)`. You should check with `console.log` to see what you have inside file object

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Would you happen to know how I can utilize setFile and setTitle so that it takes in both inputs? A general idea would be helpful, thank you for your feedback

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get the file by adding setFile(file) in my onAddImage function. Now title is the only one that is coming up as undefined. After logging file onto my consolse I got the following: File {name: 'anime-titans-shingeki-no-kyojin-wallpaper-preview.jpeg', lastModified: 1647011800228, lastModifiedDate: Fri Mar 11 2022 10:16:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 17663, …}. So I don't believe title is apart of the object, but is that necessary? I am storing the filename with a timestamp in my DB, and I have another column which is the title inputted

Comment: If you get it in file as title it should set also for state. For title change your append like this const blob = new Blob([title], {type : 'text/plain'})
formData.append('title', blob)